# When do sefardim begin reciting selihot?

Tags: calendar, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, rosh-chodesh-new-month, selichot, elul

Since rosh hodesh Elul is a mini-holiday do you need to wait till the day after rosh hodesh or do sefardim begin saying selihot on the first of Elul?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2529

Comment: IME they start the night after Rosh Chodesh. Probably there are various customs.

Comment: @doubleaa, what does IME stand for?

Comment: @AniYodea in my experience

Answer (score 1):

They start after Rosh chodesh.
Source: http://www.sephardichazzanut.com/Selichot.htm

> Starting after Rosh Hodesh Elul, Sephardic Jews around the world wake up in the early morning to recite the Selichot which consist of special prayers and poems.

Comment: Motze rosh hodesh or the following morning?

Comment: @AniYodea don't know, I'm not sefardi. But from the quote, it seems that it's the morning